# Cambiar la disposición de “yyyy/mm/dd” a “dd/mm/yyyy” en Mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, formularios, date

estoy haciendo un formulario de registro en html y quiero guardar el campo de la fecha de nacimiento en formato 'dd/mm/yyyy' pero en la base de datos solo acepta recogerlo como 'yyyy/mm/dd'.

Hay alguna forma de cambiarlo en el script de la bbdd? o en php se debe cambiar esta disposición para que se guarde en la bbdd con el formato que permite?

Comment: Mejor sería que cojas la fecha en el formato que quieras, y luego lo conviertas al formato de MySQL. Te quitarás muchos dolores de cabeza futuros. Si. Se puede cambiar desde PHP. Revisa los objetos datetime, hay bastante info por aquí en SO

Comment: Yo respetaría el formato de fechas de MySQL y haría el cambio de formatos en PHP que es mucho más limpio.

Comment: Para hacer eso tendrías que cambiar el tipo de dato en la columna a VARCHAR. Pero seria un gravísimo error, **el formato es algo relativo**, si en un contexto lo necesitas como dd/mm/yyyy en otro puedes necesitar dd/mm o en otro mm/yy y millones de formatos. Además, podrías necesitar hacer cálculos con las fechas, verificar intervalos, etc. Es por eso que querer cambiar el formato de fechas en el origen es absurdo. **Guárdalas cómo está establecido y aplica el formato que necesites en el contexto**, así tu fecha servirá para millones de situaciones.

Answer (score 0):

viendo tu necesidad la verdad concuerdo mucho con los demás ya que es mejor respetar el formato de MYSQL y el cambio lo deberias de hacer en PHP, en este comentario dan la solución a tu problema.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48947472/how-to-insert-a-date-in-the-format-dd-mm-yy-in-mysql

---

Si en caso quieres hacerlo desde MYSQL puedes usar estas funciones las cuales te pueden ayudar a recuperar o insertar en un determinado formato.

`STR_TO_DATE` : convierte un string en date. Ejemplo para insertar una fecha `dd/mm/YYYY`

```
INSERT INTO tabla (fecha) VALUES( STR_TO_DATE('31/01/2018', '%d/%m/%Y') );
```

`DATE_FORMAT:` da formato a un campo del tipo date

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%W %M %Y') FROM tabla;
```

Puedes consultar en este link la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) de MYSQL sobre las funciones para trabajar con fechas. Saludos :)

Answer (score 0):

La regla para guardar las fechas en mysql es 'yyyy/mm/dd/', pero al mostrarlo al usuario puedes cambiar ese formato, te dejo un código de ejemplo y espero te sirva...

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET["fecha_creacion"]))    
{
    $fecha_creacion = $_REQUEST['fecha_creacion'];
    //Al rescatar el dato de fecha se devuelve su formato original para que no haya problema al guardarlo en la base de datos
    $fecha_creacion = strtotime('NOW');
    $fecha_creacion = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$fecha_creacion);
}
//FECHA Y HORA ACTUAL 
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
?>
<form method="get" action="save.php">
<label>Fecha:</label>
<input type="" name="fecha_creacion" id="fecha_creacion" value="<?=date('d/m/Y')?>">
<button type="submit" name="guardar">Guardar</button>
</form>
```